# 3D Plots and vector fields

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, image3d

I'm a beginner. How I make a 3D Plot from zero? (like a graphics with the potencial of the electric field). I have to make vector fields too. (vectors of the electric field). I search at internet but I don't understand, I need help.

```
data = Import["/Volumes/CARMEN/teste.txt"];
SetOptions[{ListContourPlot, ListPlot3D}, ImageSize -> 300];
{ListContourPlot[data, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], 
ContourLines -> True, Contours -> 20, AspectRatio -> Full, 
ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
ListPlot3D[data, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, Mesh -> None, 
InterpolationOrder -> 3, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", 
BoxRatios -> Automatic]}
```

Why the graphics don't appear?

Comment: @Jens What is wrong with the code? The graphics don't appear. data = Import["/Volumes/CARMEN/teste.txt"];
SetOptions[{ListContourPlot, ListPlot3D}, ImageSize -> 300];
{ListContourPlot[data, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 14], 
  ContourLines -> True, Contours -> 20, AspectRatio -> Full, 
  ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}], 
 ListPlot3D[data, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14}, Mesh -> None, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors", 
  BoxRatios -> Automatic]}

Comment: @Jens Only appear numbers like a table.

Comment: It's impossible to say without having the data file. To get an answer, please provide a minimal working example for `data`. It probably has the wrong format. I guess it's supposed to contain the potential.

Comment: @Jens https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4adlm8h8l9oqlog/AADF0fapg2KNlvf9z09WBUwda?dl=0

Comment: @Jens In this link, I put the data.